# Flutter - How to take real time input feed from camera and scan any object?

Tags: android, opencv, flutter, image-scanner

I'm building an application to scan a document by taking real-time camera feed and detect document in that feed. I'm very beginner in the flutter, I have already done it in the python using OpenCV with the following steps A. Get Image B. Convert image to Greyscale C. Detect Edge (Apply any edge detector) D. Find Contours E. Find Biggest Contour F. Apply Warp Perspective and lastly G. Get Scanned Document.

My question is, is there any package available to do this task? if not then what is the way to implement these points as I have mentioned above?

Comment: have you found any solution to connect flutter live camera and opencv?

Answer (score 3):

While there is a Flutter [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/opencv) for OpenCV and it works with Android only, it is still not complete.

The best solution is to integrate the OpenCV native sdk for both Android and IOS and invoke them through [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Comment: I tried using open_cv package but not helping. So I started building my own. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AjayKumar can you guide me regarding the same implementation in the flutter. How can I achieve this?